# How to create a shared object across all controls that appears at the bottom of Visual Studio Winforms designer?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to create an instance of an object that has to be set to each control's specific property.

As is VS designer just creates a separate instance for each control.

How do I do this so that my shared object shows up at the bottom of the VS designer window, like a timer, or a imagelist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Things' end up in the bottom Part if they are derived from Component but *not* from Control.

I think you are looking for a Provider derived class (like ToolTip, HelpProvider and ErrorPorvider).

It would look like:

```
public class MyProvider : Component, IExtenderProvider  {  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that's it. How do you do that?

Comment: Why do you need IExtenderProvider?

Comment: Timer is (just) a Component, ToolTip is Component, IExtenderProvider. Play with ToolTip to see the diff.

Comment: Thanks I think Component was what I needed.